# Eigenvalues of a subset of matrix semigroup

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, polynomials, nonnegative-matrices

My apologies for slightly longer post but I wanted to explain lower dimensional cases and their proofs before asking the actual question, which starts after the phrase *The general case* below.

**A two-dimensional example**

Consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. We note that both of the matrices have eigenvalue $1$. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the semigroup generated by positive powers of $A$ and $B$ and $\mathcal{M} \subset\mathcal{S}$ be the subset of matrices $R$ such that the reduced expression of $R$ (in terms of word in $A$ and $B$) contains both $A$ and $B$. Note: $\mathcal{S}$ only consists of finite words of such types.

Clearly, any element in $\mathcal{S}\setminus\mathcal{M}$ will still have eigenvalue $1$. On the other hand, if $R\in\mathcal{M}$, it is easy to see that all entries of $R$ and $R^{2}$ is positive. We can show that the characteristic polynomial of $R$ cannot be reducible.

Assume the contrary. Then, eigenvalues of $R$ are either both $+1$ or both $-1$. By the Perron-Frobenius theorem, $R$ has a dominant positive eigenvalue $\lambda$ and the second eigenvalue $\mu$ is such that $|\mu| < \lambda$, which is a contradiction.

**The three-dimensional example**

Consider the three-dimensional case of this problem. We take $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}\in\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$, where $A_{i}$ is obtained from the identity matrix $I_{3}$, upon replacing its $i^{\text{th}}$ column by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{T}$. Now, we consider the subset $\mathcal{M}_{3}$ of the semigroup generated by $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}$, which consists of finite words which has each of $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}$ appear at least once in their reduced word expression. Somewhat of a same method, with slight more work, we obtain that no matrix in $\mathcal{M}$ can have reducible characteristic polynomial.

Assume to the contrary. Then, one of the eigenvalue of $R$ is either $+1$ or $-1$. If $R$ has eigenvalue $-1$, then $R^{2}$ has eigenvalue $1$. Therefore, without loss of generality, we will assume that $R$ has eigenvalue $1$ by replacing $R$ by $R^{2}$. We can employ Perron-Frobenius theorem again to say that $R$ has a dominant eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Let $\vec{x}$ be an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$. Employing a version of power method, we can show that $R^{k}\vec{x}$ converges to a vector in $\lambda$-eigenspace. On the other hand, $R^{k}\vec{x} =  \vec{x}$ for every $k \geq 1$. Therefore, $\lambda = 1$ must be the dominant eigenvalue.

But $\lambda = 1$ being dominant eigenvalue is a contradiction to the fact that $R\in\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$. So, characteristic polynomial of $R$ must be irreducible.

**The general case**

Say we take $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, A_{4}\in\mathrm{SL}(4,\mathbb{Z})$, where $A_{i}$ is obtained from $I_{4}$ by replacing the $i^{\text{th}}$ column with $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{T}$. Now, $\mathcal{S}$ be the corresponding semigroup and $\mathcal{M}$ be the subset consisting of matrices $R$ that have each of $A_{i}$s in their reduced word expression.

I suspect that my proofs from the 2 and 3 dimensional cases should generalize to larger dimensions too. However, one of the hurdles is that a degree $4$ polynomial may be reducible without having a rational root. I still want to show that any matrix in $\mathcal{M}$ has irreducible characteristic polynomial. A large amount of computation with examples indicates this to be true. I also have a proof for the words of the form $A_{1}^{n_{1}} A_{2}^{n_{2}} A_{3}^{n_{3}} A_{4}^{n_{4}}$. But for words of larger length, I have not been able to prove it. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, references, general thoughts on this problem.